# php sql search issues

Tags: php, sql

ok here is my code maybe someone out there can explain what I am doing wrong here as I just don't get it.  My understanding of this is that IF the stmt finds a result it will then run the code in the {} and hence return a result.  And IF there is no result then it would return nothing, as the IF statement is false.  But I am getting a return in postman even though the ID that I am searching is false.  It does not exist on the table.  Why do I get a return?

```
 public function getDoc($ID){

  if(  $xromstmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT adegree, bdegree, cset, dset FROM xromdb WHERE ID = ?"))  {

    $xromstmt->bind_param("s", $ID);
    $xromstmt->execute(); 
    $xromstmt->bind_result($adegree, $bdegree, $cset, $dset);

    $xromstmt->fetch(); 
    $evalxrom = array();
    $edocxrom = array();

 some other code here dealing with the return etc... }  <-- the end bracket 
to the if statement.  There is nothing past this bracket.

     } bracket to getDoc
```

Comment: Why should you're `prepare()` return `false`. Looks valid to me. The query executes inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Your if  condition only _prepares_ the statement, it doesn’t execute it or check what the result of that was.

Comment: Is `xromdb` the database name or the table name?

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: xromdb is the table name  the database name should work find as the prepare statement in con works in other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` statement that you have is just checking that the `prepare` was successful. To see if there was any data returned from the query, you need to check the result of the call to `fetch`. Try something like this:

```
if ($xromstmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT adegree, bdegree, cset, dset FROM xromdb WHERE ID = ?"))  {
    $xromstmt->bind_param("s", $ID);
    $xromstmt->execute(); 
    $xromstmt->bind_result($adegree, $bdegree, $cset, $dset);
    if ($xromstmt->fetch()) {
        $evalxrom = array();
        $edocxrom = array();
        ...
        some other code here dealing with the return etc...
    }
}
```

You should probably also check the result of the call to `execute`.

Comment: this makes more sense. ok, I knew there was something off with my thinking.  Thank both of you.  I will try this and get back at you.

Comment: Oh sorry for the slow response.  Got helped up on my 9 to 5 half way into fixing it and couldn't get back to coding till this morning.  I started to run into a problem I think because I had multiple sql searches going.  But I started kicking it around in slim and it's worked out well.  I got the results I was looking for.  I thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `$xromstmt->prepare` statement does not search the database it sets-up the search; the database is not searched until `$xromstmt->execute`. The execute and prepare statements will return true or false if the statement was run correctly (i.e. no errors in your code) regardless of whether any results were found.

What you want is to use is the number of rows from the query, 0 if no results found:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($xromstmt)
```

then run if statements of $num_rows
Hope this helps